# how to add to a dictionary from a list with certain conditions

Tags: python

I need to convert my_list into a dict with conditions

```
  my_list = ['DES', '-1007,00', 'PF2', 'RBB', 'S3C', 'U9E', 'W43', '1007,00', 'YOS', '4KF', '165,29', '5K0', '9WJ', '8E8E', '425,62', 'UL']
```

the first parameter is the name
the second is a number, but if the second parameter is not a number, then the value of the previous parameter is 0.
Here's an example from my_list:
"DES" is name and "-1007,00" is a number -> I will get

```
{"DES": -1007,00}
```

PF2 is a name, but 'RBB' is not a  number, -> I will get

```
{"PF2": 0},
```

and so on

the end result in my example should look like

```
{'DES': '-1007,00', 'PF2': 0, 'RBB': 0, 'S3C': 0, 'U9E': 0, 'W43': '1007,00', 'YOS': 0, '4KF': '165,29', '5K0': 0, '9WJ': 0, '8E8E': '425,62', 'UL': 0}
```

I tryed ->

```
import re
regexMoney = r"[-]?\d{1,}\,\d{1,}"
my_list = ['DES', '-1007,00', 'PF2', 'RBB', 'S3C', 'U9E', 'W43', '1007,00', 'YOS', '4KF', '165,29', '5K0', '9WJ', '8E8E', '425,62', 'UL']
b = {my_list[i]: my_list[i+1] if re.findall(regexMoney, my_list[i+1]) else 0 for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2)}
```

but got

```
{'DES': '-1007,00', 'PF2': 0, 'S3C': 0, 'W43': '1007,00', 'YOS': 0, '165,29': 0, '9WJ': 0, '425,62': 0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a "classic" CS101 answer would be to use a loop, look ahead, and advance the index as necessary:

```py
result = {}
i = 0
while i < len(my_list):
    cur = my_list[i]
    if (i<len(my_list)-1) and re.match(regexMoney, my_list[i+1]):
        result[cur] = my_list[i+1]
        i += 2
    else:
        result[cur] = 0
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using more_itertools, funcy or similar neat libraries I'd do

```py
import re
MONEY = r"[-]?\d{1,}\,\d{1,}"


def transform(v):
    return v if re.match(MONEY, v) else 0


l = ["DES", "-1007,00", "PF2", "RBB", "S3C", "U9E", ...]
assert len(l) % 2 == 0

d = {l[2 * i]: l[2 * i + 1] for i in range(len(l) // 2)}
d1 = {k: transform(v) for k, v in d.items()}

print(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = " ".join(my_list)
di = {}
regex1 = re.compile(r'(\w+\s+[-]?\d+,\d{2}|\w+)')
regex2 = re.compile(r'[-]?\d+,\d{2}')

lst = re.split(regex1, my_list)
for st in lst:
    match = re.search(regex2, st)
    if match:
        k, v = st.split()
        di[k] = v
    elif st.strip():
        di[st] = 0
    
    pprint(di)
    
    {'4KF': '165,29',
     '5K0': 0,
     '8E8E': '425,62',
     '9WJ': 0,
     'DES': '-1007,00',
     'PF2': 0,
     'RBB': 0,
     'S3C': 0,
     'U9E': 0,
     'UL': 0,
     'W43': '1007,00',
     'YOS': 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a python loop and an iterator here:

```
from itertools import pairwise
import re

regexMoney = re.compile(r'[-]?\d{1,}\,\d{1,}')

out = {}
it = pairwise(my_list+[0])

for k, v in it:                        # for each pair
    if regexMoney.fullmatch(str(v)):   # if the second item is a match
        out[k] = v                     # add a new key
        next(it, None)                 # consume the next pair (if any)
    else:
        out[k] = 0                     # if not a match, add 0
```

Output:

```
{'DES': '-1007,00',
 'PF2': 0,
 'RBB': 0,
 'S3C': 0,
 'U9E': 0,
 'W43': '1007,00',
 'YOS': 0,
 '4KF': '165,29',
 '5K0': 0,
 '9WJ': 0,
 '8E8E': '425,62',
 'UL': 0}
```

Comment: The result is wrong {'DES': 0, 'PF2': 'RBB', 'RBB': 'S3C', 'S3C': 'U9E', 'U9E': 'W43', 'W43': 0, 'YOS': '4KF', '4KF': 0, '5K0': '9WJ', '9WJ': '8E8E', '8E8E': 0, 'UL': '0'}

Comment: @Evg how is it "wrong"? [Reproducible example](http://t.ly/BY0QB)

Comment: I mean, he result is not correct

Comment: Are you sure you used the [latest version](/revisions/77134590/3) of my answer? I had refactored my initial code short after posting and introduced a typo but I fixed it almost immediately (it was 40 minutes ago).